# c++ 2008 convert double to string without making it into exponentials for big values of double/int

Tags: c++, c++03

I am using following function to convert a double(mostly int) to string, it is doing good for values <1000000, but for >1000000 it is giving answers in exponential `1e+06` i want it to show full string instead of converting it to exponentials. ** I am using c++ <2008 so please post relevant answers for the same**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
std::string toString(double C)
    {
      stringstream  tmp;
      tmp << C;
      return tmp.str();
    }

int main()
{
    cout<<toString(1000000)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Next question will likely be how do I get rid of the decimal point and trailing zeroes. I'll see if I can dig up an existing answer for that as well

Comment: @ouchane.exe That doesn't work, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm not finding a good one for reining in the precision, so `tmp << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0) << C;`

Comment: it is not about cout and scientific notation, I am using this function to convert the double value to string and then save it to xml, i think the function toString is returning value as exponential and i want all the numbers not exponential. cout is only for showing a reproducible example

Comment: `cout` and `tmp` are streams. Everything you can do to `cout` you can do to `tmp`. The difference here is `cout` writes to the console and `tmp` writes to a buffer you can transform into a `std::string`.

Comment: [Demonstration](https://ideone.com/xzYKx8)

Comment: thanks a ton @user4581301 i understand it now.